How to merge excel data to pdf (editable pdf) using excel vba marco? (bulk quantity)
I have an excel file and I want to merge the data to one pdf templates and make many different copies of PDF (Save as new PDF files to a folder).
I take reference from a youtube turotial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uU55FCbPHCI
I have done some parts but the problem is I don't want to print the pdf.
However, the process in the Youtube tutorial involve printing pdf.
After I delete some lines, I think I mess up the marco code.
Can someone please kindly help me to fix the code? Thank you very much.
The code is as below:
Sub PDFTemplate()
Dim PDFFIdr As FileDialog
Set PDFFldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With PDFFldr
    .Title = "Select PDF files to attach"
    .Filters.Add "PDF Types Files", "*.pdf", 1
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B11").Value = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NoSelection:
End Sub



Sub SavePDFFolder()
Dim PDFFIdr As FileDialog
Set PDFFldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With PDFFldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NoSelection:
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B12").Value = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NoSelection:
End Sub



Sub CreatePDFForms()
    Dim PDFTemplate As String
     Dim NewPDFName As String
       Dim SavePDFFolder As String
     Dim ReceiptNo As String
   Dim PaidDate As Date
    Dim CustRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
   

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row ' Find the last row in column A
        PDFTemplateFile = .Range("B11").Value
        SavePDFFolder = .Range("B12").Value
        
     If PDFTemplateFile = "" Or SavePDFFolder = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please select both a PDF template and a save folder.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Open the PDF template file maximized
        Shell "explorer.exe """ & PDFTemplateFile & """", vbMaximizedFocus

        ' Wait for a short time to ensure the PDF opens (adjust as needed)
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        

        
        For CustRow = 2 To 2
             ReceiptNo = .Range("A" & CustRow).Value
            PaidDate = .Range("C" & CustRow).Value
            ReceivedFrom = .Range("B" & CustRow).Value

            ' Send data to the PDF form
            Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
            Application.SendKeys ReceiptNo, True
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

            Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
            Application.SendKeys PaidDate, True
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

            Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
            Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
             Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
            Application.SendKeys ReceivedFrom, True
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")


  ' Save As dialog to save the PDF in the specified folder with a new name
            Application.SendKeys "^+s", True ' Ctrl+Shift+S to open Save As dialog
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

            FileName = SavePDFFolder & "\" & ReceiptNo & " " & PaidDate & ".pdf"
            Application.SendKeys FileName, True
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

            Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
        Next CustRow
    End With
End Sub


How is the macro not working? Is there no way for you to recover the lines you deleted? Side note: instead of deleting lines, it's often a good idea to comment them out.
